# Cannot write to array inside while loop - Subscript is get only

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am having the error -

Cannot assign through subscript: subscript is read only

This occurs when trying to write elements of an array inside a while loop as can be seen in code below. I understand this could be caused by swift mutability however my understanding of this is poor/nil and I'm struggling to find documentation.

Code -

```
while (counter != ((localArray.count) + 1))
        {
            data[counter] = /// The error flags on this line for the data array
                [
                    "type" : localArray[counter][0],
                    "details"  : localArray[counter][1],
                    "cost" : localArray[counter][2]
                ]
            counter = counter + 1

        }
```

EDIT for D4ttatraya -

'data' is declared as

```
var data: [[String: String]]?
```

and localArray is a copy of the result of a function -

```
var result: [[String]] = []
let localArray = result
```

Comment: Friend, please show what `localArray` and `data` looks like? I mean declaration...

Comment: @D4ttatraya edited for you to include these

Comment: what is _counter_ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First instead of declaring type of `data` array, create empty `data` array

```
var data = [[String: String]]()
```

Second I would suggest you to replace while loop with for-each loop for each inner array inside `localArray` (then instead of using `counter` variable you can use elements inside each `array`).

```
for array in localArray {
}
```

Now in loop you can just append new element to `data` array

```
data.append(["type": array[0],
             "details": array[1],
             "cost": array[2]])
```

also at the beginning of the loop make sure that each `array` has three elements inside, if hasn't continue to other inner array

```
guard array.count == 3 else { continue }
```

So the whole for-each loop should look like this:

```
for array in localArray {
    guard array.count == 3 else { continue }
    data.append(["type": array[0],
                 "details": array[1],
                 "cost": array[2]])
}
```

Comment: @JermainD, this is what I was about to post as an answer! Along with this, also make sure that `array` always have 3 elements in every sub-array, otherwise `array[0]` or `array[1]`or `array[2]`will crash.

Answer (score 1):

You data is optional so you need to create it before you can add stuff to it, also you are enumerating through localArray in order and then just adding to the end of data so you can do something like this

```
var data = [[String: String]]();

for theLocal in localArray {
    data.append([
            "type" : theLocal[0],
            "details"  : theLocal[1],
            "cost" : theLocal[2]
        ]);
}
```

Comment: Even this is also a smart approach!

Answer (score 0):

`data` is an optional, but you're trying to access it as a non-optional value. Try `data?[counter]` or `if var data = data { data[counter] = ... }`

Comment: You cannot change **data** as you're doing inside the block because data will be a _let constant_

Comment: Good point - not enough coffee this morning. Edited to var to unwrap the optional and make `data` mutable.